# Android Drive API examples not working

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I've followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/) and [running](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos) this [code](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos). File and folder creation examples work fine. But example to "Retrieve file contents", "Creating file under a folder" doesn't work. They keep giving error message like this: "DriveId is not found. Are you authorized to see this file". I've made sure that the "EXISTING_FILE_ID" does exist (first, created a file and then used its file id to retrieve contents). I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Anyone out there got these examples working ?

Comment: Your 'EXISTING_FILE_ID' complaint might have been addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-drive-android-api%5D+EXISTING_FILE_ID).

Answer (score 0):

The demos you're pointing to *do work* in my environment, and the way you put the question is too broad to answer. More like a complaint. You have to be more specific if you want to get a specific help (code causing problem, ...). So there is nothing to answer here...

I can only point you to another piece of code, [this DEMO](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo), that may get you off-the-ground. It takes a different path to show the basic GDAA's CRUD functionality of Google Drive. You may have a better luck.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers ! I wish GDAA provided some straightforward way to get resourceId for file/folder.

Comment: Here's my [cheatsheet](https://github.com/seanpjanson/GDAADemo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/andyscan/gdrtdemo/GDAA.java#L312). Be careful though, it may take a while [until you get it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api) from GDAA.