# Google Drive API Folder/Child ID

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Does anyone knows if the google folder id changes over time? Assuming, obviously, the folder is not deleted and recreated.

I'm trying to be limit the quota usage as much as possible, by storing the ID on our side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**  (2015/09/01)  Per 'BSEs' comment below.

Sorry, I assumed it is Android (being professionally distorted). 
Anyway, to make sure, look at the ID string in question and compare it with the ID you get from **drive.google.com > right click > Get link**. You should see something like:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1mqwertyasdfghZxCvbItM0E
```

If the `id=` string matches your resource ID, you're cool. Sorry for the confusion.

**ORIGINAL** (incorrect for .NET, applies to GooPlaySvcs/GDAA on Android)

**I believe it does.**

When testing the ResourceId availability [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874657/unpredictable-result-of-driveid-getresourceid-in-google-drive-android-api/31553269#31553269), I remember getting DriveId in one form immediately in the '*onResult()*' callback. Later, when the '*onCompletion()*' event occured, the DriveId of the same object looked very different (applies to both file and folder) .

Also, look at *Daniel's* comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800257/where-did-the-createfromresourceid-go/21832136#21832136), it suggests that you should not rely on the value of the DriveId in any moment and use 'equals()'.

The ResourceId would be more appropriate ID to store, shuttle around, etc... DriveId is useless outside the GooPlaySvcs instance. And, based on some hints from Drive-Involved-Googlers, relying on a concrete value of DriveId is dangerous. That makes existence of 'encodeToString() / decodeFromString()' somewhat questionable, right?

Good Luck

Comment: Since, I'm using the .net drive api. I believe, that the ID returned by Files.List() It's a resource ID and not Folder ID. If this is true, should I assume that this is Unique for me to store? .

Comment: Thanks. The ID I get from the ID from the API is exactly the same as the one from "Get Link" .

Comment: In addition, this ID is the only also shown when file/folder is being shared. This must be unique, otherwise if it does changes then everyone's share wouldn't work after sometime. I'll accept this.